# SQL Server error on Maintenance Plan: could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plans

We're using the solution of Hallengren for the maintenance of the database.

The Maintenance of Hallengren we use is **SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance**. cc IndexOptimize

Lately, we're getting the following error on a specific table:

> **could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement**

```
DBCC CHECKDB returns no errors.
```

The error is found when we manually run the procedure (We have scheduled a job to do this but since we were unable to see the error we manually run it to see what happens).

We have found the table that the problem occurs.

Is there any idea on how to proceed with the resolution of the above statement?

Comment: I suggest that you add to your post exactly *where* you get that error. From any of Ola's jobs? If so, which job? Or from some application? Etc. More details are better.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi i have updated the case. what else may i add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understand it, the error comes from the execution of IndexOptimize.

I believe that you can in the CommandLog table find exectly what SQL command that caused the error. For this, IMO, to make sense, it should be a SELECT using NOLOCK. If you have other operations modifying data, while this SELECT is executed, then yes, you can get this error.

If the error in fact come from your application, then you have to consider that instead.

In any case, options for handling this include not using NOLOCK, ignoring the error, use optimistic concurrency instead of pessimistic (for instance setting read_committed_snapshot for the database), looking at indexes (adding/removing indexes might improve things), ... Which is best for you we can't say, it is based on your circumstances.